Using something like MyDataFrame.print() instead of print(MyDataFrame)?
When I run a script from the Spyder console using runfile, source file lines containing expressions (e.g., "HELLO") don't print out to the console.  I have to explicitly print, e.g., print("HELLO").
Is there a way to output the string representation of a pandas DataFrame using a method?  Something like the very last chained method below:
dfShipName[['ShpNm','ShipNamesPrShpNm']] \
   .drop_duplicates() \
   .groupby('ShipNamesPrShpNm',as_index=False)['ShipNamesPrShpNm'] \
   .agg(['count']) \
   .rename(columns={'count':'nShpNm'}) \
   .sort_values(by='nShpNm',ascending=False) \
   .head(20).print()

I could encapsulate the entire thing (sans .print()) in a print() invocation, but that's another level of indentation.  Just appending a print()-like method avoids having to be much more cleaner, which makes a big difference when I have lots of these (for exploratory analysis).  I can also toggle the output by simply commenting away the .print().

Have you considered using Jupyter instead? It behaves more like the Python REPL and automatically shows the last result - not just printed but actually fancy-formatted using HTML for dataframes for example. IDEs have Jupyter plugins, like Spyder has Spyder Notebook (though I haven't used it myself).

I can say with some confidence that getting used to Jupyter would be an enormous detour for me.  I also like the idea of a script where I can run the sections en masse or where I can cut and paste sections into the Spyder console as needed.  I do see the notebook advantages of Jupyter, and I may use it at some point.

"I can run the sections en masse or where I can cut and paste sections into the Spyder console as needed" - You can also do that in Jupyter by breaking your code into cells.

From what I've seen, it's notebook style with code and text interleaved.  I may some day move in that direction, but it's not something I'm used to presently.  But thanks for pointing out my misconception.

I would just save the dataframe to a variable and print the variable.
In any case, you can use pipe to achieve the behavior you're looking for:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})

df.add(4).pipe(print)

   a
0  5
1  6
2  7


So great!  I was going to ask why .add(4), but that's just to show the appending of .pipe(print) to a series of chained methods.  Thanks!

Unfortunately, it can't be appended to Dataframe.to_string().  The latter has been a suggestion to print an entire DataFrame , and it returns a Python native str object.  I've tried other ways to print an entire DataFrame, but am still working that problem out.

@user2153235 If you're using to_string to set things like min_rows=100, you can use instead pd.set_option("display.min_rows", 100). Other than that, to_string returns the regular string representation of a dataframe, same as using print.

I didn't explore the issue of limited number of rows very much.  The Q&A I cite above was driven by the limited number of columns.  The display.min_rows  solution was far from ideal.

@user2153235 Sorry, I hadn't seen the link in your comment. I'm not sure I understand your problem, but if you need to use to_string along with my solution, you can use a lambda: df.add(4).pipe(lambda df: print(df.to_string()))

Thanks!  Looking forward to trying it out in the office on Monday.  This is really giving my fledgling understanding of Python a good workout! BTW, I don't want to save it to a variable and print the variable because it's only for showing results, not for retaining the dataframe.  I want to keep the Spyder Variable Explorer lean, and the code in my script lean by minimizing creation of variables that I don't want to keep.

Thanks, @e-motta.  It works great.  If I define def PrtDFstr( DF ): print(DF.to_string()) at the top of my script, then I can issue df.pipe(PrtDFstr).  For convenience, PrtDFstr() can also return DF.

I tried this for a few days and found that def PrtDFstr( DF ): print(DF.to_string(index=False)) uses screen space more efficiently.  Furthermore, adding return DF uses too much screen space because the returned DataFrame gets printed again at the Spyder console (in those cases where it isn't assigned to anything or is not followed by other chained methods). I tried assigning the returned DataFrame to the throw-away variable _, but that stops Spyder's default behaviour of using _ for the last result that was not assigned to a variable.  Not even del _ brings back the default behaviour

To achieve a method like MyDataFrame.print(), you can create a custom extension method for pandas DataFrames. Something like:
@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("print")
class PrintAccessor:
    def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
        self._obj = pandas_obj

    def __call__(self):
        print(self._obj)
        return self._obj # Return the DataFrame for further chaining

Example usage:
data = {
    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.print()

Output:
   A  B
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  7
3  4  8


Why return self._obj? Shouldn't it return None? Is that to allow you to see the intermediate value in the middle of a chain?

Yes, returning self._obj is helpful to inspect intermediate results while continuing to chain further operations on the DataFrame. If you don’t need to continue chaining, you can return None.

Thanks.  I'm may resort to that in the future.  I'm not at a point where I feel comfortable detouring into defining my own extensions at the present (because of other things I have to progress).
